# A Problem with Dirichlet process mixture model (DPMM)

Tags: clustering, nonparametric, dirichlet-process

I know that DPMM is a non-parametric Bayesian clustering model which can automatically determine the number of clusters based on data. However, which kind of clusters does the model find?

For example, I have one dataset which contains 4 dimensions. I use the DPMM to cluster this dataset based on original values, then I obtain 54 clusters. Then I transform the values by Log10, then I obtain 27 clusters. I feel so strange about these two results. Then how to explain this?